# Android intercept/inject/hook calls

Tags: android, overriding, hook

I want to have some log statements called automatically (without any work on the developers part).

For example, below is the default `MainActivity` class for the demo HelloWorld app (generated by Android Studio). I've deleted most of the method body code for conciseness:

```
package com.example.androiddemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.example.androidlogger.*;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidLogger  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Whenever the `onCreate`, `onCreateOptionsMenu`, `onClick` or `onOptionsItemSelected` functions are called, I want to first log something (maybe the function name and a message of some sort). My idea was to override the calls and so I created a separate module called `androidlogger`:

```
package com.example.androidlogger;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.view.Menu;

public class AndroidLogger extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        Log.i("AndroidLogger", "onCreate method called at: " + currentDateandTime);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("AndroidLogger", "Clicked from AndroidLogger");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.i("AndroidLogger", "onCreateOptionsMenu from AndroidLogger");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("AndroidLogger", "onOptionsItemSelected from AndroidLogger");
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`MainActivity` itself extends `AndroidLogger`, which itself extends `AppCompatActivity`. This works, but it requires the developer to always called `super.XYZ`. For example: `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`, `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`, `MainActivity.super.onClick(view);`, etc.

Is there another way to do this but without the developer needing to call super each time? Perhaps I can `hook` specific calls?